# Embed a browser in a asp.net web-based tool

Tags: java, asp.net, applet, browser, webbrowser-control

[Note: I have modified my original post to provide some clarifications - m.e.]

Does anyone know of a way to embed a web browser within a web page, e.g. through a Java applet or similar mechanism? I have reviewed the discussion on various solutions for embedding a browser in a Java application.  However, this will not work for our web-based tool, which is built on an asp.net framework. Using a Java applet is our current idea, but if you have other suggestions to address this issue, please post those as well!

This is to be used in a web-based tool that guides middle school, high school, and college students to read websites critically. The tool provides a set of guiding questions and other information along with a data-entry box surrounding the actual 3rd party web-page being viewed. The purpose of our tool is to allow teachers to choose websites for students to view and analyze - or allow students to choose the sites themselves.  We (/the tool) do not control what sites or types of media are chosen.

We are currently loading the web-page in an IFrame, but that technique is limited in several ways.  It does not provide full control for browser-like features we would like to provide, and is very sensitive to changes in both third party web-sites and to browser versions used by students.  The most difficult issue we have pertains to anti-hijacking mechanisms used on the third-party sites.  For good reasons, they use mechanisms that make them impossible to load into an iFrame -- that is, when you try to load the page into the iFrame, it will take over the entire browser window.  Not only will the page not load WITHIN our frame, it will actually make our application "disappear", thereby making it impossible for students to use these sites within our tool, and potentially also causing students to lose their work.

The tool, which has take several years to develop, is currently web-based for a variety of reasons based on the needs of our users. I would appreciate any advice or insights the community may have!

Thanks.

Comment: Are the web pages that are displayed controlled by you?  If so, a JEditorPane is a possible option.  BTW - I am not convinced there is any requirement here that a Java applet can add value to (over JavaScript & HTML).

Comment: No, they are not controlled by us. The purpose is to allow students to review any webpage (or other online materials, such as videos, etc) within our tool.  One issue we've been having with Javascript & HTML as well as some other tools we've found online (such as "bitty browser") is that web pages' anti-hijacking mechanisms make the web pages take over the browser window.  One example is NYtimes.com .  

Just to clarify, this is for educational purposes. We do not modify the sites in any way or take credit for them. The purpose is to allow students to practice reading sites critically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have web application (ASP.NET page as you described), use web-based solutions, i.e. IFrame, etc.

Web browser controls anyway is a desktop solution.

Comment: IFrame is not meeting our current needs...please see my response to the first commenter.  Thanks!